# Draw a custom shape using SVG path Bezier curve

Tags: svg, path, bezier

Is it possible to draw a path like the image below? It is basically a circle with gaps in between.

I was just able to make a circle so far using SVG path -
http://jsfiddle.net/k6pgpze6/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="500px" height="500px">    
      <path 
            d="
            M 100, 250          
            a 150,150 0 1,0 300,0
            a 150,150 0 1,0 -300,0
            "
      />
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: when you say "like the image below", do you mean with that exact look, or are you simply looking for a sequence of arcs that, taken together, suggest a circle? Because it looks like you made that image by taking a circle and clipping out some bits, which you can just as easily do in SVG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes is the basic answer.  You could draw individual arcs (ie. one `<path>` per arc), or you can have a path with multiple subpaths.

```
<path d="M 100,250 a 150,150 0 1,0 300,0
         M 300,0   a 150,150 0 1,0 -300,0" />
```

However these lines won't end with the oblique angles that your picture has.  If you want those, then your best bet is to draw a complete circle and use a `<clipPath>` or `<mask>` to make the gaps.

**Update**

Here's an approximation of your picture.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="500px" height="500px">    
      <path transform="translate(250,250)"
            fill="none"
            stroke="black"
            stroke-width="6"
            d="M 39,-145          
               A 150,150, 0,0,1, 106,106
               M 0,150
               A 150,150, 0,0,1, -106,106
               M -123,86
               A 150,150, 0,0,1, -150,0
               M -149,-13
               A 150,150, 0,0,1, -39,-145" />
</svg>
```

To make it easier for myself, I've centred the circle at (0,0) and used a transform to move it to the right place on the page.  Because I used this trick, it is easier to make sure all my coordinates (the M vales and the last two values in the A) are on the circle's circumference.  It's just a bit of simple trigonometry (`sin(angle)*150` and `cos(angle)*150`).

The trickiest part of an arc command is the large arc flag and sweep flag.  The following diagram from [the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) is useful to look at.

[image: explanation of the arc flags]

In your case, you will want to use the same value for all the sweep flags (fifth value in the arc command).  Choose either 1 or 0 depending on whether you are going clockwise or anti-clockwise around the circle.

For the large arc flag (fourth value), use 0 if your arc covers less than 180 degrees, or 1 if it is greater than 180 degrees.

Comment: I tried creating individual arcs ( using single path for each) but the measurements don't add up and look like a circle as a whole.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code to create a perfect circled arc?

Comment: @tempid you may be able to work something out based on http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/path/donut-shop.html (that shows how to get a circle path)